# Maximum of function abs

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, functions, maxima-minima

Let function $f(x)=|2x^3-15x+m-5|+9x$ for $x\in\left[0,3\right]$ and $m\in R$. Given that $\max f(x) =60$ with $x\in\left[0,3\right]$, find $m$.

I know how to solve this kind of problem for $g(x)=|2x^3−15x+m−5|$. However, the $+9x$ is confusing me.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have not idea to solve it. if only u=$|2x^3-15x+m-5|$ then easy but f(x) =u+9x then i have not idea

Comment: Start by finding out for which x, u(x)>0. Then make two cases,  $u(x)>0$ and $<0$, and calculate their max separately in the respective domains ($\{x\in[0,3]:u(x)>0\}$ and $\{x\in[0,3]:u(x)\leq 0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:

Let $2x^3-15x+m-5\gt0$ at the point where maximum occurs.

Then our $f(x)$ becomes $2x^3-6x+m-5$

note that $f(x)$ decreases for $(0,1)$ and then increases for $x\gt1$ so the maximum of $f(x)$ is at $x=3$(as $x\in\left[0,3\right]$)

Plugging in the $f(3)=60$ we get $m = 29$.

We can put in $x=3$ and $m = 29$  in $2x^3-6x+m-5$ and verify that it is positive.

Case 2 :

Let $2x^3-15x+m-5\lt0$ at the point where maximum occurs

Then our $f(x)$ becomes $-2x^3+24x-m+5$

This function increases in $(0,2)$ and then decreases for $x\gt2$ so maximum for $f(x)$ is at $x=2$

Putting $f(2)=60$ we get $m=-23$.

We can put in $x=2$ and $m = -23$  in $-2x^3+24x-m+5$ and verify that it is negative.

So we get $m= \left({29\ \ and\ -23}\right)$

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: @SarGe I understand what you meant to say and I am aware of site policies now but what would you suggest I do now? Shall I delete the answer? I cannot see how to reduce it to hints

Comment: This time it's ok, take care next time. What I suggest is just give away some hints to pure problem or "no-clue" questions posted without any work and not to pay much attention other than flagging for closure. However, you have your freedom to do anything to enjoy your experience on this site but as a responsible user of this site it's my duty to let you know the site policies.